# Java8 Date and Time with Instant API

Tags: datetime, java-8, java-time

I get dynamic date from my request,

```
Instant duration = request.getStartDate();   // my input is 2020-03-01T00:00:01Z
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  duration  = duration.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth ());
}
```

Basically i wanted to get first day of every month for 12 months, i tried with above code but getting exception,

```
java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: DayOfMonth
```

My output could be,

```
2020-04-01T00:00:01Z
2020-05-01T00:00:01Z
2020-06-01T00:00:01Z
:
:
2021-03-01T00:00:01Z
```

anything am missing here? tried with using `plus()`

```
duration.plus(30, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

I tried to convert instant to locateDate, then it prints fine, but for my required format i need to convert to Instant from localdate. I'm not seeing 1st day of next month.

```
2019-03-31T22:00:00Z
2019-04-30T22:00:00Z
2019-05-31T22:00:00Z
2019-06-30T22:00:00Z
2019-07-31T22:00:00Z
2019-08-31T22:00:00Z
2019-09-30T22:00:00Z
2019-10-31T23:00:00Z
2019-11-30T23:00:00Z
2019-12-31T23:00:00Z
```

any suggestion are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why do you call an instant a duration? Two totally different concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Instant startInstant = request.getStartDate();
LocalDate start = startInstant.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate().withDayOfMonth(1);
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    System.out.println(start.plusMonths(i).atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Much less fiddly than my namesake's answer: provided you convert to an `OffsetDateTime` up-front, there is no problem using the nice human-readable adjuster that you were trying to use initially.

```
OffsetDateTime duration = Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    duration = duration.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfNextMonth());
}
```

The issue is that an `Instant` is an unambiguous point in time, irrespective of any specific timezone or geographic location. There is no specific date associated with an instant; what is Monday the 1st in one location may be Sunday the 31st in another, but it's still the same instant. That is why when trying to set a first day of the month, you get an exception.

If you convert to an `OffsetDateTime`, you are applying an offset (in this case UTC, so an offset of zero). This converts your data to a format in which a date is unambiguous.

Comment: Thank you Michael for detailed explanation!